# How do I “activate” a Gun Mettle contract?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I bought into the Gun Mettle campaign.

My HUD says I have 2 “inactive” contracts. I'm already on the class and map specified in them. Clicking on them gives me objectives and a misformatted tooltip:

[image: (Contracts drawer)]

[image: (Tooltip with only the letters "T" and "C")]

Does them being “inactive” mean I have to activate them? If so, how do I do that?

If not, why aren't they active — is there some other condition I'm not meeting?

Comment: I think you can press f2 in game, and click on an inactive contract, and it will say at the bottom why it's inactive.

Comment: @Kyranstar The text at the bottom end of the contract seems to be only flavor. The tooltip (which I suspect is what you're referring to) is illegible. An answer listing the possible reasons for inactivity would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons I know of for a contract not being active. One is you are the wrong class for the contract the other is you are not on a Valve server. The easiest way to join a Valve server is to use the quick play feature and select gun mettle.

Many 3rd party servers are displaying gun mettle in their servername now but contracts will not work on them, they will just be hosting the new maps etc...

If you hover over the contract it will also give you the reasons for the contract not being active via a tooltip.

[image]

Comment: There is no text like that on the bottom of my contract. See the screenshots in my question.

Comment: I know which means you have encountered a bug. There are sometimes UI scaling issues on TF2 what resolution are you running. Regardless I believe I have made clear how to get contracts working.

Comment: Ok I was wrong that information is in the tooltip which you can not see as yours is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Are you playing on a Valve server?  Meaning one you accessed through Quick-Play.  If you are not, the contracts are invalidated (I suppose to stop farming maps).

Comment: This does seem plausible, but I've played on Valve servers and it still says inactive.

Comment: ...and it worked the second time I tried today. Guess it's just glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried joining a Valve server and choosing the proper class again. The second time today, it worked. Guess it's just glitchy.